# how to switch to a frame set within a frame in selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: Html]

I want to access elements under frame xxx_info_new . This is the code flow and i get no such frame exception when i try to access xxx_info_new frame

```
 Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
 Driver.SwitchTo().Frame("border_bottom");
 Driver.SwitchTo().Frame("xxx_info_new");
```

Comment: WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, "xxx_info_new")))

Comment: Try to print out page source after you have switched to `border_bottom` frame. Can you see that your `xxx_info_new` as a part of your page source?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, we can switch over the elements in frames using 3 ways.

- By Index
- By Name or Id
- By Web Element locator

**If XXXX_info_new is a child of any other frame then you need to switch to that and then current `XXXX_info_new`**

So here you have name

```
Driver.SwitchTo().Frame("XXXX_info_new")  // put the correct name as you have hide it in image
```

Source:

https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html

Comment: yes i switched to border_bottom frame first and then trying to switch to xxx_info_new frame

Comment: Does you have multiple id as xxx id in html

Comment: try xpath as Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(Driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//frame[@name='XXX_info_new']")))

Comment: put some wait also before doing it

Answer (score 0):

This works

Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(border_bottom).SwitchTo().Frame(xxx_info_new);